# Searching for strings in multiple XML-files

Tags: xml, string, perl, wildcard

I'm a not a perl/programmer by trade but I have run into some problems which can be solved with a perl-script.

I want to search through multiple XML-files that is automatically outputted by a server. The software names the files with timestamps which makes it hard to know the names of the files beforehand, but I do know the folder that that they are located in.

How can I make this code search through every file in the folder and look for a specific string e.g *.xml?

This is the code I have been using, it takes one filename and the string search function works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file;

for $file (@ARGV) {
# print "\n -----\n";
my $lines = slurp($file);
# print " File contains:\n$lines";

print "\n";
if ( $lines =~ /false/ ) {
 print " Searched for string 'false' in @ARGV";
 print "\n";
 print " String found!\n";
}
  else {
   print " Searched for string 'false' in @ARGV";
   print "\n";
   print " No hit!\n";
  }
}

sub slurp {

my ($file) = shift;
my ($f);
open( $f, "<", $file ) || die " Can't open file $file, quitting.\n";
my $scalar = do { local $/; <$f> };
return $scalar;
}  

exit(0);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your directory as first argument to your script instead of a list of files and then go through the directory:

```
...
opendir(DIR, $ARGV[0]) or die "cannot open directory $ARGV[0]: $!\n";
my @xmlfiles = grep(/\.xml$/,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);    

foreach (@xmlfiles) {
    slurp($_);
    ...
}
...
```

If its only the directory you're actually in you want, you can also use `glob` :

`my @xmlfiles = glob("*.xml");`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use **File::Find::Rule**:

```
use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.xml')->in($seach_dir);
```